# Any solution to get coordinate WITHOUT using API (not networking)

Tags: web-scraping, coordinate

I'm looking for some solution to get coordinate from address or any WITHOUT using an API.

Usually, we use the Google Maps API, but at this time we can't use an API over the internet because of our budget.

Is there any solution??

---

purpose : scrape some web site, such as the one below

sample web site : https://www.yelp.com/biz/honey-badger-brooklyn-2?osq=Restaurants

return : [ lat, lon ]

lang : python

framework : Scrapy

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking for here - you **need** some mapping of `[street address]->[lat,long]`, which generally comes in the form of a large database, for example the one Google Maps has in its back end.

There is no way to calculate the coordinates of an address without such a database, so you either need to get a database of your own (likely by buying existing data from another company), or use an API call to a service that accesses such a database for you.